# How to read ConnectStream in HttpWebReqest

Tags: c#, .net, stream, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I'm running into a wall when trying to read underlying streams of either HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse classes. As it turns out, these are not memory streams; they are of type ConnectStream. The problem with this type of stream is that it doesn't support reading, writing, seeking, nothing. Every time I try to do something with this type of stream I get not supported exceptions.

Is there a way to use some other type of stream in place of ConnectStream that would actually be readable?

Code:

```
public class BaseAsmxProxy : SoapHttpClientProtocol
{
    protected override System.Xml.XmlReader GetReaderForMessage(SoapClientMessage message, int bufferSize)
    {
        string responseXml = GetResponseDataFromStream(message.Stream);

        return base.GetReaderForMessage(message, bufferSize);
    }

    private string GetResponseDataFromStream(System.IO.Stream stream)
    {
        string returnValue = null;

        long initialPosition = stream.Position;
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
        returnValue = reader.ReadToEnd();

        stream.Seek(initialPosition, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

Note that when I use a SoapExtension (for some other functionality) it switches stream types and I inadvertently get MemoryStream here that is actually readable - which is exactly what I need. However, I'll have to turn off SoapExtentensions at some point and that's where the problems start to occur: ConnectStream is simply not readable.

Comment: Please show the code you're trying to use. Perhaps you're accessing the streams at the wrong point in time, for example.

Comment: What do you really want to do? There might be another way than trying to use the underlying streams?

Comment: added additional info... @jgauffin I'm trying to get ahold of underlying streams in order to read XML data for logging purposes.

Answer (score 1):

The response stream can only be read once. You need to use a `MemoryStream` for all processing.

Comment: That wouldn't be a problem if I had any choice. But the stream type is ConnectStream, which apparently doesn't support any normal read/seek operations that MemoryStream does. Is there a way to force HttpWebResponse to use MemoryStream instead?

Comment: No. You can either encapsulate all calls to `HttpWebRequest` / `HttpWebResponse` in a class, or you can derive them and use `public new Stream GetResponseStream()` to override the original implementation. You can also take a look at the Moles project from Microsoft (although I strongly discourage you from that solution).